# Flagging and editing for all questions in Android app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app

This has to do with the context menu on questions. When I open the menu for a question where I am the OP I'm presented with:

[image: when I'm op]

and then when I view the menu on a question I'm not OP:

[image: when I'm not OP]

When I'm the OP, I'm allowed to edit it, but not flag/close the question. But on other questions, I can't edit but I can flag/close. On the desktop/mobile site, we're allowed to flag our own questions, and edit other questions. Is it possible to merge these menu's together and get editing and flagging for all questions in the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was done on purpose because the API currently doesn't access the same edit queues as the website so if you're trying to edit something that you don't have the privilege to do it'll respond with an error. I think this is better than not letting people edit at all though, even though it would be disappointing to go through the effort of editing something and seeing an error message, so I'm going to enable editing for all questions.

Flagging should've already been possible on all questions, it was a bug that it wasn't.

Both of these are done for version 0.1.62.

Comment: Could you do a privilege/rep check for the site the user is using, and present a message and/or prevent them from editing if their edit would go to the edit queue? But if it's going to be implemented in the future, this solution works for me in the alpha!

Comment: Privilege checking is a whole can of worms that is [status-planned] for now, but not present in the API or app at the moment. I figure it's not going to be a common problem for people in the alpha at the moment so why not risk it :)